# Force Class implementing interface with Java generics

Tags: java, generics

I have following problem with Java generics and could not figure out how to solve it.

```
interface IJob {
     void doJob();
}
```

This is how a job is described, it has a key and the class definition.
Later on in the code I want to create an object of the type `Description.clazz` via reflection

```
class Description<T extends IJob> {
     String key;
     Class<T> clazz;
}
```

With this method I want to add jobs to my map.
To avoid runtime exceptions (`ClassCastException`) I want to force that the passed description is implementing the interface `IJob`.

```
Map<String, Description<IJob>> jobs;

public void addJob(Description<IJob> description)
{
    jobs.put(description.key, description);
}
```

This are the jobs, and what I expected was that `JobA` could not be add to my map because it does not implement `IJob`, but it does. The compiler throws no error, and a simple unit test succeeds without an exception during runtime.

```
class JobA
{
}

class JobB implements IJob
{
    @override
    void doJob();
}
```

How should I define my `Description` and the method `addJob` to force a compiler error?

EDIT:
This is an example how i am adding a job.

```
void addMyJobs()
{
    Description d = new Description();
    d.key = "A";
    d.clazz = JobA.class; //why does this compile?
    addJob(d);
    d = new Description();
    d.key = "B";
    d.clazz = JobB.class;
    addJob(d);
}
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Show the code that you think should cause a compiler error.

Comment: i have edited the question and added the part where the jobs are added to the map.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: change this line `Description d = new Description();` as `Description<IJob> d = new Description();` you will achieve what you asked in  your question.
Because `Description d` is a raw type while `Description<IJob> d ` is not a Raw Type.

Comment: @VikrantKashyap this does not compile also for `JobB`, although`JobB` implements `IJob`. Compiler says "IJob" required, "JobB" found.